# How to authenticate slack app OAuth flow with external app?

Tags: oauth, slack, slack-api, slack-bolt, slack-bot

I am building external application that needs to integrate with slack application.
Currently I've built the application and it uses jwt token to authenticate it's users.

Now the issue that I have is related to slack integration. I've built slack application that uses OAUTH flow and can be installed in workspaces(teams) but the app can be installed regardles if current user is authenticated with my external app. Can somebody describe me what is the flow if I want to first authenticate through my external application and then allow slack app installation. Otherwise if user can't authenticate through external app I want to throw error and stop installation.

I tried redirecting somehow to the external application but I wasn't sure if this was going to work.